# How to combine case statement patterns

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to match on many different constructors in a case statement. For simplicity, assume in half the cases we do the same thing, and in the other half we do something else. Even if I factor out the logic to another function, I still have to write:

```
case x of
  C1 -> foo x
  C2 -> foo x
  ...
  C10 -> bar x
  C11 -> bar x
  ...
```

Is there some way to make case statements behave more like `switch` statements in C (i.e. with fallthrough), or so that I can match on one of many patterns at once, like:

```
case x of
  C1, C2, C3 -> foo x
  C10, C11, C12 -> bar x
```

Or perhaps another way to clean this up?

Comment: I made `x` an argument to `foo` and `bar` as this is my use case. It also prevents an ugly but correct answer of using a separate partitioning function to merge equivalent constructors into a common case (like `C1 -> C1, C2 -> C1, C3 -> C1`, and then only match on `C1`).

Comment: Note that there is a currently dormant [proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/43) to introduce "or patterns"

Comment: The proposal for "or patterns" has been accepted by now: https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0522-or-patterns.rst

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are called *disjunctive patterns*, and Haskell does not have them. (OCaml and F# do.) There are a few typical workarounds, however. If your type is an enumeration, you can use equality, with for example `elem`, using a `case` expression, guards, or `MultiWayIf`:

```
exampleCase cond = case cond of
  c
    | c `elem` [C1, C2, C3] -> foo
    | c `elem` [C10, C11, C12] -> bar
    | otherwise -> baz
```

```
exampleGuards c
  | c `elem` [C1, C2, C3] -> foo
  | c `elem` [C10, C11, C12] -> bar
  | otherwise -> baz
```

```
exampleIf c
  = additionalProcessing $ if
    | c `elem` [C1, C2, C3] -> foo
    | c `elem` [C10, C11, C12] -> bar
    | otherwise -> baz
```

And of course, if `foo` or `bar` are long expressions, thanks to laziness you can simply factor them into local definitions, so you only have to repeat the name and any pattern variables you need as arguments:

```
exampleWhere cond = case cond of
  C1 x -> foo x
  C2 y -> foo y
  …
  C10 -> bar
  C11 -> bar
  …
  where
    foo x = something long (involving x, presumably)
    bar = if you please then something else quite long
```

If you frequently group constructors together in this way, you can use the `PatternSynonyms` language option, which is especially useful in conjunction with `ViewPatterns`, to make your own patterns for matching such groups:

```
{-# Language
    LambdaCase,
    PatternSynonyms,
    ViewPatterns #-}

-- Write one function to match each property.

fooish :: T -> Maybe X
fooish = \ case
  C1 x -> Just x
  C2 x -> Just x
  …
  C10 -> Nothing
  C11 -> Nothing
  …
  -- May use a wildcard ‘_’ here; I prefer not to,
  -- to require updating cases when a type changes.

barrish :: T -> Bool
barrish = \ case
  C1{} -> False
  C2{} -> False
  …
  C10 -> True
  C11 -> True
  …

-- Create synonyms for matching those properties.
-- (These happen to be unidirectional only.)

pattern Fooish :: T -> Foo
pattern Fooish x <- (fooish -> Just x)

pattern Barrish :: T -> Bar
pattern Barrish <- (barrish -> True)

-- If they cover all cases, tell the compiler so.
-- This helps produce useful warnings with ‘-Wall’.

{-# Complete Fooish, Barrish #-}

-- Use them just like normal patterns.

exampleSynonyms x = case x of
  Fooish x -> …
  …
  Barrish -> …
  …
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested in [further discussions](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/cl6uy0/why_arent_disjunctive_patterns_supported/)...