# Multiple pattern match

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Hello can someone please explain me how can i do the following in haskell:

```
f :: Char -> Bool
f 'a' = someMethod
f 'b' = someMethod
f 'c' = someMethod
f _ = someOtherMethod
```

Can i do somehow something similar to the `@` pattern :

```
f :: Char -> Bool
f x@(pattern1 || pattern2 ...pattern n) = sameMethod x
```

Basically I want to apply the same method for multiple patterns .Is this possible? I do not want to write N pattern match lines that basically do the same thing.

**P.S** My method that i want to implement is the following :

```
readContent::String->Maybe [Double]
readContent (x:xs)=go [] [](x:xs) where
    go _ ls [] =if length length ls > 0  then Just ls else Nothing
    go small big (x:xs)= case x of
                           '}' -> Just (small:big) -- i want some other pattern here too
                           ',' -> go [] small:big  xs 
                            t@(_) -> go  t:small big xs
```

I am parsing a `String` that can be delimited by `}`,`{` and `,`. For `}` and `{` i want to apply the same method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine case statement patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246108/how-to-combine-case-statement-patterns)

Comment: Hopefully we get [or-patterns sometime not too far in the future](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/43)

Answer (score 7):

In this particular example, you could use a **guard**:

```
f :: Char -> Bool
f x | x `elem` "abc" = someMethod
f _ = someOtherMethod
```

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian The above technique still applies, you can use ``case x of y | y `elem` "{}" -> ...``

Comment: Oh you can place guards before the `->` ?